# Sharepoint Designer 2010 won't display lists of libraries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

Not quite sure what I've done to screw up SPD2010 (was working), but it displayed

```
Sharepoint Designer cannot display the item

  What you can try:
    Click refresh ... blah

  Most likely causes
    The file has been deleted from the site
    The site is encountering problems
```

I can't see anything related in event viewer. I think is web service related as I think the queries are made via a WS?

Comment: One extra bit of info - I have installed ASP.NET using the "aspnet_regiis -i", and I have a feeling it may have worked previously :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was caused by a "phantom" list definition. I experienced a number of other problems (some in SP some in SPD), all generating variations of this error;

```
    <nativehr>0x8107058a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

The problem list definition was deployed and undeployed from VS2010, so I have no idea why it was still around! The Sharepoint UI wont allow you to remove it (errors as above), so the trick is to use the **stsadm** powershell command with **forcedeletelist** as detailed here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262609(office.12).aspx

Hope this helps someone else !

Comment: Deleting a solution from Sharepoint doesn't delete the data (lists, items) that were created using the solution's definitions. This happens only if the solution includes code to remove them when it is retracted/deleted. Of course, you may just have hit a bug in SP 2010.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it wasn’t a solution. So, I made a backup of the site collection before to try anything. After a lot of time and different problems I figured out that some lists were causing the missreading. I tried one more time to get the lists in SharePoint Designer 2010 just to cause some entries in the log. After that I opened the log file and looked for something like: “Failed to determine the setup path of the list schema for feature {GUID}, list template XXX.”. With the GUID I looked for a match here. http://sharepoint-geek.com/2010/10/08/sharepoint-2007-moss-features/
With the feature name I used this blog: http://aurramu.blogspot.com/2011/03/failed-determine-setup-path-of-list.html.
With the feature re-installed I went to SPD and it worked like a charm.
I hope it helps someone else.